# How to use wp-cli.yml file?

Tags: wp-cli

I am trying to set up a `wp-cli.yml` file but every time I run the command, the file is ignored.

Where should the file be located?
And how should I call the command to use it?

I tried having a file in the project's root directory, as well as a folder above. I have also tried using the following file names:

`wp-cli.local.yml`,
`wp-cli.yml`

The I tried running something like:

```
wp local core download
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress install.
>       Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`.

**PS:** I am not sure wp-cli questions are off topic because I see tons of questions about wp-cli with answers, and I also see that there's a wp-cli tag. If this questions is off topic, please let me know before down voting it, and I will remove it.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR**:

1. Run `wp --version --debug`
2. Check that `wp-cli.yml` was found
3. Check that the `ABSPATH` set by WP-CLI matches the directory where WP is installed
4. Look at `find_wp_root()` for hints about why it's finding the wrong folder

---

The docs say:

> inside the current working directory **(or upwards)**

...so you should be able to use it in parent directories, not just in the directory where you call `wp` from. i.e., you should be able to have it several levels above the folder where Core is installed, and then call it from anywhere below the directory where `wp-cli.yml` is installed [[1](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/5090616a38b920f1d1b71cf8046757749503424b/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php#L91)].

## Was `wp-cli.yml` included?

You can find out by running `wp --version --debug`

- Found: `Debug: Using project config: /var/www/example.localhost/wp-cli.yml (0.012s)`
- NOT Found: `Debug: No project config found (0.014s)`

## Is WP-CLI's `ABSPATH` set correctly?

*Note: This is the `ABSPATH` that WP-CLI defines internally, **not** the one from your `wp-config.php`*

WP-CLI's internal `ABSPATH` is what it uses to find WordPress [[2](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/5090616a38b920f1d1b71cf8046757749503424b/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php#L565), [3](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/5090616a38b920f1d1b71cf8046757749503424b/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php#L553)], so if it's wrong then you'll get the `This does not seem to be a WordPress install` error.

To find out if it's wrong, you can run `wp --version --debug` from a few different directories, and look at the `ABSPATH` output. Does it match the actual path to the folder where Core is installed?

Assuming the path to WP is `/var/www/example.localhost/web/wordpress/`, then:

- Correct: `Debug: ABSPATH defined: ABSPATH defined: /var/www/example.localhost/web/wordpress/ (0.013s)`
- Incorrect: `Debug: ABSPATH defined: /var/www/example.localhost/web/content/plugins/akismet/wordpress/ (0.019s)`

Keep in mind that any arguments passed via parameters (e.g., `wp --path=foo`) will override the values in `wp-cli.yml`.

## Why is `ABSPATH` wrong?

There are probably lots of different causes for it being wrong, because it depends on how your folder structure is setup, the `path` defined in `wp-cli.yml`, etc.

`ABSPATH` is set to the value of `find_wp_root()`[[4], [5], [6]], so that's where you need to start troubleshooting.

You can read through `find_wp_root()` and mentally step through the code, looking for clues. If you have WP-CLI [installed via composer](http://wp-cli.org/docs/pull-requests/), then you can also edit `Runner.php` to add debugging output to `find_wp_root()`, use Xdebug, etc.

In my case, I had a Bash alias setup for `wp` that was passing `--path` to the command, which was overriding the `path` set in `wp-cli.yml`, but I'd forgotten about it.

[4]: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/5090616a38b920f1d1b71cf8046757749503424b/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php#L199)
[5]: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/5090616a38b920f1d1b71cf8046757749503424b/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php#L753)
[6]: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/5090616a38b920f1d1b71cf8046757749503424b/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php#L160

Comment: Fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/) wp-cli.yml should be in the working directory where you are calling `wp` commands. Inside the file you should have the path to the WordPress install relative to the file's location.

Using [VVV](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) as an example, the file structure would have a `site-name` folder where I would call the 'WP_CLI' commands. Inside that directory is an `htdocs` folder where the WordPress files are located and the `wp-cli.yml` file that contains this:

```
path: htdocs
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

with me it works with me this way

```
path: E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress
```

it should be added to wp-cli.yml which located at the same directory where the wp cli is installed
i use it in windows so i used full path not relative